# PCMan increases file size dramatically on destination drive (data rescue attempt (win7 not booting after crash)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, data-recovery, knoppix

**1TB hard drive does not fit onto 1TB external drive**

Over a week ago, my busy PC crashed whilst a number of applications were running. Since then, Windows has been suffering from dementia and presented me with a bluescreen and sequentially, with the recovery options.

On an odyssey to rescue my system and user files, I have covered several cycles of the on-board Windows recovery options. There seemed to be no end to that - without much effect.

Turned to Knoppix in order to create a disk image or - my own files, at the very least.
I have browsed the internet trying to get a basic grasp of Linux and what to do in order to rescue my data. The crashed machine has a 1 TB hard drive, fdisk -l shows 1000.2. I bought an ext. drive (1 TB) converted from the preinstalled FAT32 to NTFS, which seemed to have worked.

There was software on the ext. drive, taking up around 70 GB. I deleted the software, but similar to a Mac, the amount of free space on the ext. drive stayed the same - maybe I am too sleepy but I could not find a solution.

I will go out and get a 2 TB drive today and attempt to write a disk image to the new drive with ddrescue, since it has been described as very suitable for a potentially damaged drive, using code copied off a blog and hoping for the best.

This looks like it could be yet another futile attempt?

As the copying or cloning apparently can take an awfully long time, I wanted to save at least my own files from 2 userprofiles in the meantime. Their combined size a fraction of the disk space on the 1 TB ext. drive. As I have not enough Linux experience to successfully clone partitions, I resigned to using PCMan's simple drag and drop method
*- to find that PCMan increases the file size immensely on the destination drive*. looks like at the most one of the two users' data will make it across onto the ext. drive.

At my wits end, any illuminating comments appreciated, as I did not find answers on the net or reading the GNU ddrescue manual, or else may have found them incomprehensible.
I really need to get this machine and my data to work again soon.

Any pointers, explanations, or links to a easy-to-follow step-by-step mostly fool proof method for recovery of the lot -including my programs would be wonderful. Any specs you might need to know, please ask.

And no, I don't need me ears boxed for not having a suitable backup all ready and handy. I am quite self-sufficient at beating myself up. Please excuse the prosaic description.

Hope someone can help.